# How to retrieve transaction hash value from the Promise object using web3js?

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript, signature, hash

I'm trying to retrieve the transaction hash value after I call my smart contract method.

My Promise object looks like below.

```
returnPromise:  
    Promise { "pending" }
    ​
    <state>: "pending"
    ​
    <prototype>: PromiseProto
    ​​
    catch: function catch()
    ​​
    constructor: function Promise()
    ​​
    finally: function finally()
    ​​
    then: function then()
    ​​
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
    ​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
const query = smartContract.methods.buyToken(Type, Title, Desc);
const encodedABI = query.encodeABI();
const tx = {
  from: walletAddress,
  to: contractAddress,
  gas: 2000000,
  data: encodedABI,
};
returnPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
  const tran = await web3.eth
    .sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
      console.log('=> confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
    })
    .on('transactionHash', hash => {
      console.log('=> hash');
      console.log(hash);
      //console.log("HASH: ", hash);
      transHash = hash;
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
      console.log('=> reciept');
      console.log(receipt);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
});

console.log("returnPromise: " + returnPromise);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` your promise.

Your code should read:

```
await returnPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
```

Comment: I tried but received the error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators". I'm using web3js 1.0.0 beta 34

Comment: @TThom: That's got nothing to do with web3 version. As the error says, you can use `await` only from inside an `async function`.